# Convert Object type to string in typescript

Tags: generics, type-conversion

I want to implement generic class in angular 10

```
export class MyfolderService<T>{
   save(values: number[]){
     localStorage.setItem(T, values);
   }
}
```

I receive, obviusly, an error: T only refer to a type.
Any idea, how to convert a given type in to string??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. The `<T>` is just a hint for the compiler to make checks at the compile time. At the end your code will be compiled to plain JavaScript and all syntactic sugar like the generics-information will be lost.